# C++ shared_ptr manipulation logic

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, shared-ptr

I have this logic:

```
struct Foo;
struct Bar;  

struct IComponent {
    virtual Foo * GetFoo() { return nullptr; }
    virtual Bar * GetBar() { return nullptr; }
}

struct Foo : public IComponent {
    Foo * GetFoo() override { return this; }
}

struct Bar : public IComponent {
    Bar * GetBar() override { return this; }
}
```

The components are managed by

```
class SimpleObject {
  public:
     void Add(IComponent * b){
        components.push_back(b);
        if (b->GetFoo()) foo = b->GetFoo();
     }

     template <typename T>
     T * GetComponent() const {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < components.size(); i++){
           if (T * tmp = dynamic_cast<T *>(components[i])){
            return tmp;
           }
        }
        return nullptr;
     }
   
  private:
    Foo * foo;
    std::vector<IComponent *> components;
}


template <> Foo * SimpleObject::GetComponent<Foo>() const { 
    return this->foo; 
}
```

I can have multiple different `SimpleObject`. However, each of them can contain same or different components (one component can be assigned to multiple `SimpleObject`). `GetComponent` is used to only access the associated component. There should be no ownership transfer (however, I dont know how to force this since a library user can, of course incorrectly or my mistake, do this) - components are not aware of each other, only via the `SimpleObject` they are asociated to.

Now, I dont like the raw pointers. I converted `std::vector<IComponent*>` to `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IComponent>>` and `void Add(IComponent* b)` to `void Add(std::shared_ptr<IComponent> b)`.

However, I am not sure how to manage `GetComponent` method. Should I also convert its return type to `shared_ptr` or is it better to stick with the raw pointer and return it via `.get()`? The same goes for helper variable `foo`. However, in this case, I think that keeping it as a raw pointer is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want to expose ownership (let alone transfer it) as part of your interface, returning a **raw** pointer (or some special observer pointer type, if you use such) is plainly the right idea.  (In particular, avoid constructions like `const std::shared_ptr<T>& foo()` that meaninglessly express observation in terms of some ownership *elsewhere*.)  This approach also saves a bit of reference count fiddling and is compatible with your explicit specialization.